# Typescript de JSON a variables

Tags: json, typescript

Recibo de el servidor la siguiente cadena de caracteres con notación JSON

```
{'item': 'CERR', 'radius': 12.0}{'description': 'asdf', 'days_of_works': 'LV'}{'hour_init': datetime.time(15, 15, 26), 'hour_end': datetime.time(15, 15, 26)}
```

¿Existe una forma mediante un función de obtener los datos en variables o objetos? Porque no veo una forma rápida y facil de separar las variables con la notación JSON en el cliente.

Sería más facil enviar la cadena con la siguiente 'CERR'+'-'+'12.0'+'-'+.... y luego separlo en el cliente con un split('-')

Comment: Tal como argumentan en la respuesta, eso que colocas en tu pregunta no es un JSON válido. Será difícil convertirlo en JSON directamente sin antes hacer algo a nivel de cadenas.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la "cadena" que muestras daría error si la conviertes desde un string exactamente como está (no tiene comas y/o no posee un indicador de que sea un arreglo `[{}, {}]`).

Lo que buscas es: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

Ejemplo de uso:

```js
const jsonString = '[{"item": "CERR", "radius": 12.0 }, {"description": "asdf", "days_of_works": "LV"}]'

const decodedObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)

console.log('Item ->', decodedObject[0].item) // Accedemos directamente a una propiedad e imprimimos su valor. En este caso: "CERR"
```

---

### Actualización

Para acceder a todos los objetos del arreglo, puedes implementar [for ... of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterables) y para cada propiedad de los objetos, implementar [for ... in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterables). Sin embargo, esto puede llegar a ser poco óptimo, dependiendo qué tantos datos abarcan los objetos, por lo que es recomendable agrupar los modelos de datos de tal forma que no se requiera llamar a más de un objeto para el mismo contexto.

Ejemplo:

```js
let outerString = ''

for (const obj of decodedObject) { // Asumiendo que ocupamos el objeto anterior, el cual es un arreglo
  for (const propName in obj) { // Donde `propName` es el nombre de la propiedad del objeto actual de la iteración
    outerString += (outerString.length > 0 ? `-` : '') + obj[propName]
    // También puedes añadir la lógica que necesites aqui
  }
}

console.log(outerString) // Imprime "CERR-12-asdf-LV"
```

Comment: Gracias. Por que obtengo SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1?

Comment: JSON ocupa comillas dobles. Además, si un supuesto JSON empieza con `'`, entonces no es un JSON válido. un JSON debe empezar necesariamente con `{` o `[`. Si no tienes control del formato de la respuesta, vas a tener que hacer un filtro antes de la conversión

Comment: Asi es como se implementa el JSON:                data = [{"item": rubro.first().items, "radius": rubro.first().radius,
                "description": rubro.first().description,},
                
                {"days_of_works": rubro.first().days_of_works,
                "hour_init": str(rubro.first().hour_init), "hour_end": str(rubro.first().hour_end)},
                
                {"certificate": base64.b64encode(rubro.first().certificate.read()),
                "picture1": base64.b64encode(rubro.first().picture1.read()),
]

Comment: Para tenerlo claro, necesitas convertir el JSON a objeto e iterarlo? Porque si ese es el caso, puede hacerlo con un `for ... of` para iterar los objetos del arreglo, y `for ... in` para iterar las propiedades de cada objeto. Ref: [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#iterables)

Comment: Por otro lado, las funciones que estás asignadas en algunas propiedades, no tienen garantía de ser ejecutadas en tanto no estén definidas en el contexto de ejecución del script. Lo recomendable en estos casos es obtener un JSON con datos estáticos y luego implemetarlo como fuente de datos para futuras modificaciones.